# source-map for chrome in production

Tags: webpack, source-maps, web-frontend

A lot of tutorial about it, but I can't see something working.

I need 2 things:

- map file in a separate file (not inline)
- enable debugging in chrome console

I've tried all the [different types](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), but none of them match my needs.

It looks like the only ones that works with chrome console are eval-source-map & inline-source-map but they are not in a distinct file.

Other sourcemaps can be in a separate file but while debugging chrome console can not evaluate variables